# Animate 3d character on android application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 3d, android-animation, blender

I have a blender character (.blend) and I want to integrate it in my android app as an animation like this app [Hand Talk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.handtalk&hl=en), I searched on the internet and I found those solutions, but none of them  seem adequate for me:

1) import the character as obj file then load it and display it in Android with OpenGL. The problem is that I have many animation (movements) with many frame in each one and each one generate a file of 30MB which will make the app size very large if I integrate those obj files in my app.

2) Go for Unity 3d. The problem is that I will code the movements of the character using c# which is time consuming due to the large number of animations that I have.

Any new suggestions?

Comment: Why would you animate using c# when unity provides an animation tool

Comment: Can you tell me what is this tool ?

Comment: The animation tool is built in. Have a read up on unity

Comment: Is it animator ?

Comment: no thats how you control the animations and can blend them ...

Answer (score 0):

To get a 30MB file for each frame, you must be exporting a separate mesh object that has been deformed to fit each frame of animation. This is not a very efficient way to save animation data.

All you need is a mesh model of a hand and then use an armature to deform the mesh data. This reduces the animation data to only the positions of about twenty bones. The vertex positions are then calculated based on the bone positions. Armatures are used to animate whole characters in 3D games.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am working now with fbx format and I am focusing on reducing it's size